# Android : DbxAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount() always return false on Remote Service

Tags: android

On my Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private mDbxAccountManager mDbxAccountManager = null;

...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

mDbxAccountManager = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.dbx_app_key), getString(R.string.dbx_app_secret));

...
}

...

public void buttonOnClick(View view) {
if(mDbxAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount()) {
//Do something
}
else {
mDbxAccountManager.startLink(this, 0);
}

...

}



}
```

And on my Remote Service :

```
public class CloudService extends Service {
private mDbxAccountManager mDbxAccountManager = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

...

mDbxAccountManager = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.dbx_app_key), getString(R.string.dbx_app_secret));
if(!mDbxAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount()) {
return;
stopSelf();
}

...
}
}
```

The result is, after I link my app with dropbox using installed dropbox client, the hasLinkedAccount() on my Activity return true, meanwhile the same code on my Remote Service always return false.

I also check the logcat and it showed that my app already linked with dropbox.

My suspect is that the dropbox API create some SharedPreferences when it successfully link with my app, but my Remote Service can't access that or get a cached version of that SharedPreferences... I don't know...

Please help...

Thank you

Edited :
If I reinstall the app, then the result is as expected and hasLinkedAccount() return true, but if I uninstall and install again which cause clearing the user-data, then I link my app again with Dropbox, then the same strange behaviour appear again.
What I'm doing wrong? I'm turning my head almost 24-hours....

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

After trying and trying...
I get conclusion that the Service that runs before the app linked  with dropbox will always get DbxAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount() return false.
I try to kill the process by calling Process.killProcess(myservicePid) after I link my app with Dropbox and start the service again and it work.
So... I solved it by not starting the service before the app was linked with dropbox and start the service only if it already linked, because stopSelf() on the service doesn't kill the process.
I think this issue have something to do with the Context getApplicationContext() which is passed to DbxAccountManager.getInstance(), and I don't know why looks like the Context is not updated when the dropbox was link with the app.

Thank you.